# Save values in list_rbind()

Tags: r, dataframe, list, function, parallel-processing

Someone from this group helped to improve my parallelization. Now I am facing a different problem. I am having an error when running the following code

```
library(terra)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(furrr)

g <-  terra::vect("prueba.SHP")
x <- list.files(pattern="\\.tif$")

irr <- function(x) {
  
  ra <-  rast(x)
  
  segments <- cut(seq_len(nrow(g)), parallel::detectCores())
  slevels <- levels(segments)
  
  l <- future_map(slevels, function(level) {
    
    rows_to_process <- which(segments == level)
    
    map(rows_to_process, function(i) {
    
      d <- terra::extract(ra, g[i], exact = TRUE)
      d <- na.omit(d) 
      
      if (nrow(d)!=0){
        
          d <- d %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(ss = sum(fraction * d[,2])) 
          d <- ((d$ss * 250 * 250) * 100) / g[i]$area_m2
          d <- data.frame("gage"=as.numeric(g[i]$GAGE_ID),"perc_irr"=d)
      
      } else {
        
          d <- data.frame("gage"=as.numeric(g[i]$GAGE_ID),"perc_irr"=0)
      }
      
      return(d)
      
      }) %>% list_rbind()
    
  })
  
  val <- list_rbind(l)
  write.csv(val,paste(str_sub(x,end=-5),".csv",sep=""))
  
}

for(tif_file in list.files(pattern="\\.tif$")) {
  irr(tif_file)
}
```

when I am trying to run it I got the following error in the part of `map`

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

When I run separately the code of the function inside map  works fine as shown below:

```
g <-  terra::vect("prueba.SHP")
x <- list.files(pattern="\\.tif$")

for  (i in 1:nrow(g)) {
  
        ra <-  rast(x[1])
        d <- terra::extract(ra, g[i], exact = TRUE)
        d <- na.omit(d) 
        
        if (nrow(d)!=0){
          
          d <- d %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(ss = sum(fraction * d[,2])) 
          d <- ((d$ss * 250 * 250) * 100) / g[i]$area_m2
          d <- data.frame("gage"=as.numeric(g[i]$GAGE_ID),"perc_irr"=d)
          
        } else {
          
          d <- data.frame("gage"=as.numeric(g[i]$GAGE_ID),"perc_irr"=0)
        }

    print(d)
}
```

I got this from print(d) without any error and the data frames has the length expected one row for the GAGE_ID and one row for the perc_irr:

```
     gage  perc_irr
1 1013500 0.0208757
     gage perc_irr
1 1015800        0
     gage perc_irr
1 1011000        0
```

Comment: `list_rbind()` expects a list of data frames. The line `d <-list(d)` defeats that purpose, as you are turning each data frame into a list. Just return `d`.

Comment: I did the change you suggested: ```map(rows_to_process, function(i) { ...d <- data.frame("gage"=g[i]$GAGE_ID,"perc_irr"=d)}) %>% list_rbind()``` but I got the following error: ```Error in (function (.x, .f, ..., .progress = FALSE) : In index: 4. Caused by error in map(): In index: 1.Caused by error in `data.frame(): !arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0```

Comment: Then, I am sorry Phil, but I do not know what you mean for returning d

Comment: See the last line of these custom functions https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-intro/Writing-your-own-functions.html#simple-examples

Comment: Either way, your error suggests that there are some situations where nothing gets returned in `((d$ss * 250 * 250) * 100) / g[i]$area_m2` or possibly higher up. But without being able to reproduce the error, I can't investigate why.

Comment: I have wrote ```return(d)``` but I am still getting the same error. That operation that you mentioned sometimes is equal to NA, but I was thinking that was not suppose to be an error

Comment: All I can tell is that the error message is telling you that there is a situation in which a data frame is created with 1 row in the 1st variable, and 0 row in the 2nd. I'd suggest testing out your code that is inside the function to determine why it's behaving that way, and how you can account for it.

Comment: I just edited it